# Pandas DataReader

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, yahoo, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

This may be a really simple question but I am truly stuck.
I am trying to call Pandas' DataReader like:

```
from pandas.io.date import DataReader
```

but it does not get DataReader. I do not know what I am doing wrong, especially for such a simple thing. All I am trying to do is to acquire data from Yahoo Finance.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pandas data reader was removed from pandas, it is now a separate repo and a separate install

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader

From the readme.

> Starting in 0.19.0, pandas no longer supports pandas.io.data or pandas.io.wb, so you must replace your imports from pandas.io with those from pandas_datareader:

```
from pandas.io import data, wb # becomes
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
```

> Many functions from the data module have been included in the top level API.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
```

Comment: I had not, I am running into problems(or so i believe) because I operate using Pycharm

Comment: Pip should be independent of pycharm, look at the following link for info on how to install with pycharm or install/build using the python interpreter https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html